# Ratchet and native sessions

Tags: php, session, ratchet

I want to use native sessions (and not Symfony if possible) in Ratchet.

I followed and tried the following question/answer on github: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/346.

This is my code for the onOpen function:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    echo "New Connection\n";

    $cookiesRaw = $conn->httpRequest->getHeader('Cookie');

    if(count($cookiesRaw)) {
        $cookiesArr = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\parse_header($cookiesRaw)[0]; // Array of cookies
    }


    $conn->session = new \session($cookiesArr['PHPSESSID']);

    $conn->session->set('username','John');

    echo $conn->session->get('username');
}
```

And this is my session class:

```
class session {

  // the id of the client session;
  public $id;

  // take a session Id and continue a session if empty create a new session
  public function __construct($PHPSESSID = ''){

    // if we have a valid session id containing letters and numbers then use it
    // @note add check for weird characters later
    if (strlen($PHPSESSID) > 5 && preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $PHPSESSID) && preg_match('/[0-9]/', $PHPSESSID)){
      session_id($PHPSESSID);
    } else{
      session_regenerate_id();
    }

    @session_start();
    $this->id = session_id();

    unset($_SESSION); // so we cant attempt to use this directly
    session_write_close();
  }

  // return the value of a session variable or null
  public function get($var_name){
    session_id($this->id);
    @session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION[$var_name])){
      $var =  $_SESSION[$var_name];

    } else{
      $var = NULL;
    }

    unset($_SESSION);
    session_write_close();

    return $var;
  }

  // set the value of a session variable
  public function set($var_name, $var_value){
    session_id($this->id);
    @session_start();

    $_SESSION[$var_name] = $var_value;

    unset($_SESSION);
    session_write_close();
  }

}
```

This does not work. This is  the var_dump from the onOpen function:

```
object(session)#69 (1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(64) "17b755a58065c76d34f3476c686cc9a6abb77fd9aa5bae084dd24871bd3a5500"
}
```

So as you can see from the var_dump, there are no sessions in the object.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: get anywhere with this ?